# Unknown storage space limit error

Tags: macos, storage, error

I'm not sure where this error is coming from. I thought it was maybe for an old backup/sync app I used called Spideroak, but my limit there is 6gb. I have used Box, Dropbox (still do with over 12gb of free space), Spideroak, Foldersync, and Mozyhome in the past. Spideroak and Dropbox are the only two known to still be active. I only use the free 5GB iCloud backup for iOS device backups. I cannot seem to find where it's coming from.

Searching for the text string online has not yielded any results either. This is the dialog box that pops up and awaits me every morning when I get to my desk for the past couple weeks.
[image]

Also, the **Dismiss** button does just that, and **Upgrade Today** does nothing, not even providing a hint (like a tooltip or anything).

Also, ***Activity Monitor*** app doesn't appear to provide any hints from active processes either. Figured I should add that in case someone thinks of it, too. It could be something obscurely named, and I'm missing it, but nothing obvious comes to to list.

Comment: Where does the 'Upgrade Today' button take you?

Comment: great question... I'll update the original post too if I can. "Upgrade Today" button just fails. nothing to guess from on hover, nothing I can spot active in activity monitor, either. no hints that I could find anywhere.

Comment: This may be a long shot, but do you notice anything in the network section of activity monitor that might point to a program?

Comment: nothing that I'd noticed, but I really wouldn't know what to look for there... any ideas of what to look for?